# Has anyone used WebFaction hosting for large traffic websites?

Tags: web-hosting, php, mysql, traffic, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm a point where I'm needing to move a large traffic website off of MediaTemple Grid Server (it's maxing out the resources there now and they have actually asked politely for it to be moved to something more suitable) and on to a new server that can handle things better.

My first thought was setting up a VPS. The site has two main components, the website itself and a forum. The website is currently coded in PHP with MySQL and is mostly static HTML files dotted with PHP scripts. It's old and cranky and ideally I want to move it to something like Django. The forum is a Simple Machines forum written in PHP and uses MySQL. They both get a lot of traffic. Bandwidth is up in the 600mb to 1gb status a month with over 500,000 visitors and more a month. The forum gets 400+ posts a day with 40,000 visitors a day. Like I say, I was going to move each part to their own VPS. One for each.

But then I was thinking... I'm having to set this up all my self, I need to get backups sorted, I'll need to maintain the website myself. It's all alot of work, which I'm not sure I want to take on.

So... Then I thought of WebFaction. I've used them for a few small websites. I've contacted them to ask this exact same question, and they indeed said it could handle it. But they would surely say this.

I'm curious to know if anyone here has used WebFaction for large scale websites. Stuff with a lot of traffic. Can WebFaction handle large scale websites in your experience?

Comment: Don't know if you've tried but you might get a better response [here](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 2):

I have a WordPress-based client I moved to WebFaction from the MediaTemple grid, for basically the same reasons. The site was hitting limits constantly, with overages incurred and no real upgrade path other than switching to their VPS plans.

The site was transferred September 2010. Since then, normal traffic tends to range around 600-700thousand pageviews per month, with a couple months having gone as high as 1.2million. They're on a plan offering 160MB of application memory, and WebFaction has never had anything to say to us about resources to date.