# Web Hosting for a small company with a few sites

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm the web developer at a small company based in the UK and we are looking into getting web hosting.

I have been looking around for good deals, but good deals don't always mean the best hosting provider.

So far, I have seen two that 'look' to be good:

http://www.justhost.com/ and http://www.fatcow.com/

Does any one know if these are good? If so, which is the one to go for?

Also, I want to know if there are any other companies worth considering or any that are known for being excellent that either you use or know of.

Answer (score 1):

Known for excellence?  Amazon.  Rackspace.  Azure.

But, it all depends on what you are looking for there are sites like http://page.ly/plans-pricing/ which host wordpress.  It's a super premium hosting option, but your site will run awesome on it.  When you look at hosting you need to consider other things like:

- how are backups done?
- is the site critical to my business does downtime cost me money? if yes, choose something that is distributed amongst more than one server
- can someone there help me (for real) if I have a technical problem?

I use hostgator for most of my personal sites.  But, we host our business sites on our own hardware at a data center.

Comment: Amazon and Azure hosting isn't the basic hosting that this person is looking for. Rackspace is managed hosting or cloud hosting, which isn't basic either.

Answer (score 1):

I use tigertech.net for a few sites. They have awesome support and the best knowledge base I've seen out of a hosting company. I have been with them for about a year and a half and don't recall any downtime at all. They are US based though, I don't know if that makes a difference to you.

Answer (score 1):

My standard recommendation at the moment is [WebFaction](http://www.webfaction.com/). They've got servers in the US(Texas) and Europe(Amsterdam), and you can choose which you'd prefer to house your sites. Technically, it's shared hosting, but the level of access you have is much closer to a VPS, which comes in handy; and if not, you won't really be aware of it. I gave a little more detail in [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18671/has-anyone-used-webfaction-hosting-for-large-traffic-websites/18683#18683). That was based on a plan one step up from base, though note they've since consolidated their offerings into a single plan with upgrades, so you'll see different values now.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference in this class of shared hosting companies. All of them provide the same range of services (don't be fooled by advertising tricks as unlimited resources). However, for a UK company, UK IP is quite better in favor of SEO. UK hosting is a bit more expensive; but there are lots of good companies.

Comment: -1 This is a non-answer. If there are lots of them, then name one and back it up. You're basically saying "just pick one because they're all fine" which I can't imagine you actually believe if you do this professionally.

Comment: I meant Justhow and Fatcow (as asked in the question) are the same. Pick the one you wish, no technical difference.